# How do I get the "boundary" of a Delaunay triangulation?

Tags: scipy

Visually, it is clear to me that given a Delaunay triangulation, there are some points which form its "boundary". This boundary is different from a convex hull, since it is not minimal in the number of points, and it is not necessarily convex.

What is it called? Is there a way to get it from a [scipy Delaunay triangulation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html)?

(Note: I am not looking for an algorithm on how to determine this boundary, but rather a pre-baked scipy function. I already have an idea for how *I* can get the boundary of a Delaunay triangulation, but prefer to not re-invent the wheel.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually quite simple, there is no need for convex/concave hulls.

Assuming you have triangulated a closed surface, the key observation is to note that an edge of the triangulation belongs to the boundary if it's not shared by two different triangles.

From the [scipy.spatial.Delaunay documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html), If P is a set of points and you have computed T = Delaunay(P), then T.neighbors equals -1 in it's kth coordinate if the edge opposite to the kth vertex belongs to the boundary.

Example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

# Create triangulation of a rectangle
x = np.linspace(0,1,9)
y = np.linspace(0,1,9)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
P = np.array([X.flatten(),Y.flatten()]).T
T = Delaunay(P)

# Find edges at the boundary
boundary = set()
for i in range(len(T.neighbors)):
    for k in range(3):
        if (T.neighbors[i][k] == -1):
            nk1,nk2 = (k+1)%3, (k+2)%3 
            boundary.add(T.simplices[i][nk1])
            boundary.add(T.simplices[i][nk2])

# Plot result
plt.triplot(P[:,0], P[:,1], T.simplices)
plt.plot(P[:,0], P[:,1], 'o')
plt.plot(P[list(boundary),0], P[list(boundary),1], 'or')
plt.show()
```

[image: Result]

Comment: This is the answer to question I posed, but that I messed up what I wanted to ask. I needed to find a Delaunay triangulation that "minimizes the number of unnecessary edges", and then determine the boundary points. So the tricky part of the question isn't in figuring out the boundary edges of a given triangulation (as you nicely show), but getting the ["right triangulation"](https://gist.github.com/dwyerk/10561690) for a cloud of points, so that we can use the triangulation to find the cloud's "intuitive" boundary points. I was confusingly calling the "point cloud" the "triangulation".

Comment: Yes, then you were looking for a concave hull, I guess. I was actually looking for an answer to your original question, and as there was no code here I ended up contributing it. ;-)

Comment: In case this helps anyone, I think `np.unique(tri.convex_hull)` produces the same result as the code above

Comment: That would only be valid for convex geometries, while the OP specifically refers to the general case of non-necesarily convex objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is not recently present in `scipy`, it would make no sense to place it somewhere else than among the `scipy.spatial.Delaunay` object methods, and list of the methods is pretty short and doesn't contain anything that specific.

The method [find_simplex](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.find_simplex.html#scipy.spatial.Delaunay.find_simplex) might help you find the convex hull (assuming this means the smallest convex superset), but the engagement of the circumscribed circle (if I understood well the Delaunay triangulation definition) seemms like a completely new kind of obstacle.

Assuming that the `simplex` is a word for a "side" of this "triangle" , you would need to find union of all such simplexes to find the convex hull, so for the boundary you don't want all simplexex, only some of them, and here my imagination ends.